# Getting text from a file and giving value to it

Tags: php, arrays, file, file-get-contents

Been looking for the answer to my question in the posts but I cannot find something to guide me. Sorry if this has been asked before.

I have a html file called email.html. In the contents I have #user# #pass# and #text#

What I need to do is get #user# #pass# and #text# and change them for the real thing. 
The real things is data coming from database.

I've been thinking in a php file with

```
$email = file_get_contents('email.html');
```

But then I get lost, anyone can please tell me how to get the ## tags and give them value?

Please guide this sad student ;)

Thansk lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do this:

```
$email = file_get_contents('email.html');

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '#user#';
$patterns[1] = '#pass#';
$patterns[2] = '#text#';

$replacements = array();
$replacements[2] = 'user';
$replacements[1] = 'password';
$replacements[0] = 'your text';

$newEmail = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $email);
```

More info here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 2):

As long as those strings are guaranteed unique, you could simply have something like this:

Assuming your array of data for replacement looks like:

```
Array(
    'user' => 'example@exmaple.com',
    'pass' => 'foo',
    'text' => 'Welcome Mr. Example!',
);
```

then

```
foreach ($data as $tag => $datum) {
    $email = str_replace('#' . $tag . '#', $datum, $email);
}
```

#### EDIT: xil brings up a good point: arrays.

```
function addHashMarks($v) { return "#{$v}#"; }
$email = str_replace(
    array_map('addHashMarks', array_keys($data)),
    array_values($data),
    $email
);
```

IMO, there's no reason to fire up the REGEX parser if what you're doing doesn't actually use regular expressions; `str_replace` is MUCH faster.

EDIT: I had actually intended to do the `addHashMarks` part with an anonymous function, but (a) those are 5.3+ only and (b) I didn't want to introduce too many concepts at once -- but seriously, go check out anonymous functions.

Comment: Agreed this would work as long as the strings are unique. +1 for simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of this text file was a little clearer, it would be easier to help.

Look into the php function strtr()